# R shifting values of dataframe to the left while preserving headers

Tags: r, dataframe, shift

I have a csv file with headers in the form :

```
a,b,c,d
1,6,5,6,8

df <- read_csv("test.csv")
```

For some reason there's the value 1 in the example is incorrect and to correct the file, Id like to shift all the other values to the left and thus drop 1 but preserving the columns ending with :

```
a,b,c,d
6,5,6,8
```

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
headers <- names(df)
new_df <- df[, 2:length(df)]
names(new_df) <- headers
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line of code, the `structure` command creates an object and assigns attributes:

```
structure(df[,2:length(df)], names = names(df)[1:(length(df)-1)])
```

Recognizing that a data.frame is a list of equal-length vectors, where each vector represents a column, the following will also work:

```
structure(df[2:length(df)], names = names(df)[1:(length(df)-1)])
```

Note no comma in `df[1:length(df)]`.

Also, I like the trick of removing items from a vector or list using a negative index.  So I think an even cleaner bit of code is:

```
structure(df[-1], names = names(df)[-length(df)])
```